# How to integrate ocLazyLoad and Webpack or code splitting per view

Tags: angularjs, import, webpack

Hey I have an angular webapp writing in EcmaScript 5(not ES6) and I would like to intergate webpack in my current app.

My old webapp use ocLazyLoad to load scripts on demand.
Now I have created a small webapp using webpack and ocLazyLoad.

My small app use ES6 and have 3 views: Home,View1,View2.

Now I am using ui-router to do the routing between the views, I am trying to load a specific directive for specific view using ocLazyLoad.
The problem starts when I realized that my directive file is out of webpack's Enviroment and therefore import angular doesn't recognize as a legal statement.

How can I load files using ocLazyLoad and webpack if webpack demands from me to enter all the js files into one bundle.js file.

Can I do code splitting per view and if so how?

index.js

```
import "./main"
```

main.js

```
//Import third-party libraries
import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import angularCSS from 'angular-css';
import oclazyload from 'oclazyload';

//Import custom modules
import directives from './custom/modules/modules';

//Import Controllers
import homeCTRL from './custom/controllers/homeCTRL';
import viewOneCTRL from './custom/controllers/viewOneCTRL';
import viewTwoCTRL from './custom/controllers/viewTwoCTRL';


//Define app module
var app = angular.module("app",[uiRouter,angularCSS,oclazyload,directives.name]);

//Define controllers
app.controller("homeCTRL",homeCTRL);
app.controller("viewOneCTRL",viewOneCTRL);
app.controller("viewTwoCTRL",viewTwoCTRL);

//bootstrap the app
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});

/* Setup Rounting For All Pages */
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    // Redirect any unmatched url
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");

    $stateProvider
      .state("home", {
          url: "/home",
          template: require('../views/home.html'),
          data: {
              pageTitle: 'home'
          },
          controller: 'homeCTRL',         
          activetab: 'home',
          css: 'css/home.css',
          resolve: {
              deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                  return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                      name: 'app',
                      files: [
                        'src/custom/directives/directiveOne.js'
                      ]
                  });
              }]
          }
      })
       .state("view1", {
          url: "/view1",
          template: require('../views/view1.html'),
          data: {
              pageTitle: 'view1'
          },
          controller: 'viewOneCTRL',
          activetab: 'view1',
          css: 'css/view1.css'
      })
       .state("view2", {
          url: "/view2",
          template: require('../views/view2.html'),
          data: {
              pageTitle: 'view2'
          },
          controller: 'viewTwoCTRL',
          activetab: 'view2',
          css: 'css/view2.css'
      })
}]);
```

directiveOne.js(Error here)

```
import angular from 'angular';

angular.module('directives').directive('mySharedScope', function () {
    return {
        template: '<p>I am a directive One</p>'
    };
});
```

modules.js(Load modules once)

```
import angular from 'angular';

export default angular.module("directives",[]);
```

controlerHome (for example)

```
export default function($scope){
    $scope.message = "You are in homeCTRL";
};
```

my webpack config file:

```
const path = require('path');

const config = {
    entry: './src/index.js',                    /** relative address **/
    output:{
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,'build'), /** absolute path **/
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath:'./build/'
    },
    module:{
        rules:[
            {
                use: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                test: /\.js$/,

            },
            { 
                use: 'html-loader',
                test: /\.html$/
            },
            {
                use:['style-loader','css-loader'],
                test: /\.css$/,
            },
           /* {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
                use:[
                    {
                        loader:'url-loader',
                        options: { limit: 40000 } 
                    },
                    'image-webpack-loader'
                ]
            }*/
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

**Edit:**
I have tried to do code splitting but with no success, I have succedded in bring the directive but the directive doesn't work well.

```
/* Setup Rounting For All Pages */
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    // Redirect any unmatched url
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");

    $stateProvider
      .state("home", {
          url: "/home",
          template: require('../views/home.html'),
          data: {
              pageTitle: 'home'
          },
          controller: 'homeCTRL',         
          activetab: 'home',
          css: 'css/home.css',
          resolve: {
              deps: ['$ocLazyLoad','$timeout', function ($ocLazyLoad,$timeout) {
                    $timeout(function(){ 
                        var promise = System.import('../src/custom/directives/directiveOne.js')
                        promise.then(function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                        })
                    });
              }]
          }
      })
       .state("view1", {
          url: "/view1",
          template: require('../views/view1.html'),
          data: {
              pageTitle: 'view1'
          },
          controller: 'viewOneCTRL',
          activetab: 'view1',
          css: 'css/view1.css'
      })
       .state("view2", {
          url: "/view2",
          template: require('../views/view2.html'),
          data: {
              pageTitle: 'view2'
          },
          controller: 'viewTwoCTRL',
          activetab: 'view2',
          css: 'css/view2.css'
      })
}]);
```

Comment: Nobody knows the answer, is it event possible? please help it is critical question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use webpack 'dynamic imports'.
This creates a new chunk per import which can be lazy loaded with ocLazyLoad

eg
import('c3-angular') - webpack creates a new chuck when this is called and returns a promise which can be use to trigger ocLazyLoad

```
import('c3-angular').then(function(c3Ang){
    $ocLL.load({name: 'gridshore.c3js.chart'});
})
```

You can store objects with a set of promises for dependencies and the name of the module needed to pass to ocLazyLoad

eg

```
    ngTagsInput: {
        promise: Promise.all([
            import('ng-tags-input/build/ng-tags-input.min.js'),
            import('ng-tags-input/build/ng-tags-input.min.css'),
            import('ng-tags-input/build/ng-tags-input.bootstrap.min.css')
        ]),
        name: 'ngTagsInput'
    }
```